# Cocos studio script

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

I'm a complete new user of Cocos2d, I've been using Unity for many days, but now I'm looking for a lighter engine to create a simple 2d drag and drop game for Android and iOS.

I'm using Cocos Studio, I've created the scene and the Sprites, but now I don't know how to animate them. I've viewed some tutorials, but I haven't understand so much. So these are some questions:

- I've found almost all tutorials about Cocos2d-x but NOT about the Studio, so I'm wondering if the Studio is a complete IDE (like Unity) or only an editor for menus, sprites and animations...
- In the Studio, how can I create a script in javascript and attach it to the scene or the objects?
- Is there something automatic to manage gravity and collisions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to know that, cocos2d-x is very different in comparison with Unity. Cocos2d-x forcus on Coding, so the Cocostudio is just a tool which makes it easier for us to design UI, Menu, and manage Layers, Scene. Game objects such as Sprite, PhycsicsSprite... are created by Coding, you add them into your game by functions from cocos framwork. This make the performance of games seem to be more higher and smoother.